# In which overridden method of a view will I be sure that automatic layout has been attached?

Tags: android, layout

I try to create android view's programmatically.

When I use getLayoutParams() within the constructor of a view, it gives me null.
However, after I have created the instance of the object, if I run the getLayoutParams() just in the next line, I get the LayoutParams not null.
E.g.

```
 View v = new View(context); //trying getLayoutParams() in c_tor gives null
 //constructor passed..
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
 //the above line will give a filled lp OR say lp is not null.
```

Can anyone tell me if I subclass View, then in which overridden method can I be sure that the android system has generated a default layout parameter for the view and attached it already ?

Comment: The view will not have any LayoutParams unless you attach it to a layout, or set it manually via `v.setLayoutParams(lp);`

Comment: It has a layoutParams object automatically set. I do not have to set it explicitly. I can get the layoutParams object by getLayoutParams and then adjust the vars like topMargin, etc  the way I want.

Comment: No it doesn't.. only if you attach it to a layout or set it manually. (This can be proven because it returns `null` doesn't it?)